# What are the concrete classes which are used to extend or implement the build-in types in dart e.g int,double,String etc

Tags: flutter, dart

```
abstract class int extends num {
/**/
}

abstract class String implements Comparable<String>, Pattern {
/**/
}

abstract class double extends num {
/**/
}
```

Which concrete classes implement these abstract classes in dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes are not implemented in Dart, but directly inside the VM (so C++ or JS depending on the build target).

This is shown by the `external` keyword used about everywhere in their abstract class, like with:

```dart
abstract class int extends num {
  external const factory int.fromEnvironment(String name, {int defaultValue});
}
```